# Storing word in WCF Service somehow?

Tags: asp.net, algorithm, wcf

I have to make a WCF service for a school project. The project is a T9 predictive text editor. Basically what the service should do is have some method returnWords(string keycombo) or something like that, that gets the words. I have all the logic for that done, the problem is  don't quite understand how to "store" the words. I words in the orginal application were loaded from a text file then put into a Trie. I'm assuming this could still work if I can someone load the words when they start the service. How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in a few ways:

1. Standard way would be to use some database to store words.
2. I understand it's just a homework so you can go for a simple solution and store words on a text or xml file for simplicity.

In WCF services, you usually don't hold state so the words would be read each time you call a service.

If you need to cache the words, you can use the singleton pattern but you would have to be careful with the multi threaded nature of web services.

Comment: I likely can't cache stuff as he doesnt want any of the dictionary saved on the client ever(except the search results of course). If I were to use a database or xml file, does that mean I need to reconstruct my Trie everytime I connect?

Comment: Yes, without caching you have to  reconstruct every time.

Comment: :,(. Darn. Do you have any links on making the database from the text file?

Comment: Sorry, not at the moment - I'm accessing SO from my mobile for a few days.

Comment: It's fine, I'll just do some googling.